# Adding columns to a dataframe where all other columns are periods

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I have a timeseries dataframe with a PeriodIndex. I would like to use the values as column names in another dataframe and add other columns, which are not Periods. The problem is that when I create the dataframe by using only periods as column-index adding a column whos index is a string raises an error. However if I create the dataframe with a columns index that has periods and strings, then I'm able to add a columns with string indices.

```
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.normal(size=(5,2))
idx = pd.Index(pd.period_range(2011,2012,freq='A'),name=year)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=idx)
df['age'] = 0
```

This raises an error.

```
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.normal(size=(5,2))
idx = pd.Index(pd.period_range(2011,2012,freq='A'),name=year)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=idx.tolist()+['age'])
df = df.iloc[:,:-1]
df[:] = data
df['age'] = 0
```

This does not raise an error and gives my desired outcome, but doing it this way I can't assign the data in a convenient way when I create the dataframe. I would like a more elegant way of achieving the result. I wonder if this is a bug in Pandas?

Comment: Does the following do what you want: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.Series(idx).astype(str))`

Comment: Unfortunately no. The resulting columns are some integers, but not the same as the years in the PeriodIndex. This is the same problem as with using `idx.values`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is one way to get what I understood you wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.Index(pd.period_range(2011,2015,freq='A'),name='year')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'age':['age']})
df1 = df1.set_index('age')
df = df.append(df1,ignore_index=False).T
print df
```

Which gives:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, age]
Index: []
```

And it keeps you years as Periods:

```
df.columns[0]
Period('2011', 'A-DEC')
```

The same result most likely can be achieved using `.merge`.